# Is this practice thread safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Say I have a class like this.. This is just an abstract code

```
class foo
{
public:
  int a;
  static foo* pfoo;
  foo()
  {
    pfoo = this;
  }
  fooCar* pFooCar;
  void someMethod();
}
```

Now some other class might do this

```
foo::pfoo->someMethod();
```

or

```
foo::pfoo->a = 14;
```

Is this practice correct?

Should I make the static variable of the class private and wrap a getter of the static variable in a mutex?

Something like this

```
class foo
{
private:
static foo* pfoo;
public:
  int a;
  foo()
  {
    pfoo = this;
  }
  static foo* getFoo()
  {
      lock mutex..
      return pfoo
      unlock mutex..
  }
  fooCar* pFooCar;
  void someMethod();
}
```

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I hope you aren't explicitly unlocking a mutex after returning.

Comment: You will never reach `unlock` because it's after `return` statement

Comment: Why are you assigning a member `this` to a static variable in a *member constructor*? http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2012/10/21/implementing-a-thread-safe-singleton-with-c11/

Comment: I did not notice that. You are right the mutex would never be unlocked. this wont work either. Ay other suggestions ?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by threadsafe? I see no opportunity here for partial reads and writes. There are definitions of threadsafe for which this code would be threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your static `pfoo` is basically just the singleton pattern, so you can replace that `pfoo` stuff with this(Meyers singleton), which is guaranteed safe (if you want to change the pointer afterwards then this doesn't apply):

```
class foo {
public:
    static foo* getFoo() {
        static foo singleton;
        return &singleton;
    }
};
```

However, *anything* you do after you receive the pointer is not guaranteed thread-safe. But that all depends on what you need from the code. Thread-safety varies a *lot* depending on the application, particularly on the number of readers and writers.

Now if you only want a single thread to access the `foo`'s members at a time then you can just have a single mutex:

```
class foo {
std::mutex fooMutex;
int bar;
public:
    static foo* getFoo() {
        static foo singleton;
        return &singleton;
    }

    void setBar(int newBar) {
        std::lock_guard guard(fooMutex); //This goes in every function that modifies the data.
        bar = newBar;
    }

    int getBar() {
        std::lock_guard guard(fooMutex); //If simultaneous readers are allowed then remove this
        return bar;
    }
};
```

It all depends on your use case. This is just the simplest, most naive, and least efficient method of doing this. This does not work if you need to, for example, change the value of `bar` depending on its current value.

Comment: Meyers Singleton is _only_ safe with a C++11 compiler that correctly implements 'magic statics' ([N2660](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm)). This is at the moment only supported by newer versions of clang and gcc.

Comment: You're always returning the same instance of foo. The op reassigns the static on the given constructor. Are you certain that the value of 'bar' is in the canonical AX register prior to the guard going out of scope from within the getter?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your design requirement.  If there are objects of same class working on some shared data across threads, then you would need to explicitly handle the synchronize threads access to shared data.

In such cases exposing member variable via getters and setters with locks would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

No. Static variable initialization isn't thread-safe itself. In general case you should always use mutexes/spinlocks when you access to shared variables. It's not atomic.

Comment: If static variable initialization is not threadsafe, how can we initialize the mutex?

Comment: I relied on (this)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx]. `Assigning a value to a static local variable in a multithreaded application is not thread safe and we do not recommend it as a programming practice.`

Comment: Assignment and initialization are quite different. Did you mean assignment?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to wrap the assignment to the static member in an atom step; e.g., critical section, mutex, InterlockedExchangePointer. While it seems like such a simple assignment should be thread safe, it's not; i.e., the assignment is not natively atomic potentially exposing a partially assigned multibyte variable to another thread.

EDIT: sample per op's request and dropped confusing paragraph

Of course, you'll need to setup your mutex prior to using it

```
 foo()
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
    pfoo = this;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
  }


  static foo* getFoo()
  {
      foo *retval;
      pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
      retval = pfoo;
      pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
      return retval;
  }
```

Comment: Can you give an example please

Comment: Updated post to show example. Using the same mutex for the assignment and for the getter.

Comment: We could make the static of type `std::atomic<foo*>` if that is in the standard library being used.

Comment: No tearing possible on architectures that I know, assuming proper alignment.